# Newly installed ssd not visible in files

Tags: nautilus, ssd, fstab, filemanager

I have a newly installed SSD on 22.04 that I can access through the terminal as well as files. However, it does not appear in the navigation menu of the ubuntu file manager. I know that I can bookmark it, but in Ubuntu 18.04, it was not the case as I could see it with other drives.

Here is the relevant output of `lsblk`

```
nvme1n1     259:0    0 931,5G  0 disk 
└─nvme1n1p1 259:1    0 930,4G  0 part /media/rayyan/evo970
```

And here is the relevant line in `fstab`

```
/dev/nvme1n1p1 /media/rayyan/evo970 ext4      defaults        0       1
```

By the way, I also tried putting the UUID in `fstab` obtained by `/dev/disk/by-uuid/`

I also tried the `fstab` entry with `comment=x-gvfs-show` as well as `x-gvfs-show`.

---

For reference, [I have attached the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SP0lu.png) where we can see both the drives (`evo970` as well as `Ubuntu...`) as well as the navigation menu with only `Ubuntu...`

I would be grateful for any help.

---

**Update**

After trying out different things for many hours, I found a surprising behavior:

If I add *the same line* in `fstab` twice, it partially works.

This seems most probably a bug.
Example:
I have added these lines in `fstab`:

```
UUID=4a0dbb66-8512-4116-a722-8150ab900df1 /media/rayyan/evo9701 ext4 defaults 0 0
UUID=4a0dbb66-8512-4116-a722-8150ab900df1 /media/rayyan/evo9702 ext4 defaults 0 0
```

Please note that the same UUID has been mounted to two different points. Doing so makes the second mount(`/media/rayyan/evo9702`) appear in the navigation panel. However, the Disks utility shows the first mount(`/media/rayyan/evo9701`).

This seems most probably a bug. Although the repetition in `fstab` makes the ssd appear in the navigation panel, it does not seem to be a neat approach as we have now two different mounts for one ssd. [This image demonstrates this effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIelr.png).

**Update - 29.09.2022**

As per the reported issue [here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/-/issues/2516), it seems that this is the expected behavior to not show fstab mounts.

Comment: I assume from your question you are not running 18.04 now. What version are you running?

Comment: Hi @David, thanks for pointing it out. I am using 22.04 now. I have edited the question with this info.

Comment: @user68186, using system defaults was my first attempt before experimenting with `fstab`. But it did not work. I chose `/media/` explicitly because I wanted to see my drive in the navigation with other potential drives.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of Ubuntu version I believe the "missing" navigation panel entry is due to the fact that it isn't a "removable" drive.

Note: with `/media/rayyan/` visible in the file manager you can grab `evo970` and drag it into the panel, it will become a "bookmark" and remain there.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I just uninstalled 18.04 today there I had this SSD above the bookmarks with other drives. I understand that I can always bookmark it. But it still kind of bugs me to see the SSD displaced :D I cannot manually place it in the section above the bookmarks.

Perhaps it is something related to "removable" vs "non-removable" drives in 22.04 as you pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

As per the issue [here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/-/issues/2516), it seems that it is an expected behavior to NOT show the fstab mounts in the navigation panel.

P.S. I cannot accept this as answer because of low reputation points :p

Comment: You should be able to accept your own answer after the required wait time.